# Keyboard overlap the input form, it's not sliding up in ionic IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, input, keyboard, angular8

In my iPhone device, the keyboard hide the input field so whenever I type into the input field, am not able to see what it actually write, this issue is faced only in ios device

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try add ' mode="md" '

```
<html lang="en" mode="md">
```

in index.html